# How to turn off the swap only for Cassandra in Ubuntu (Linux) VM

Tags: cassandra

We are using Cassandra 3.0. And wanted to turn swap off only for Cassandra in Ubuntu VM (not at the VM level). Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn off swap completely for a certain process. However, you can change the swappiness option for it by using **cgroups**. By setting swappiness to 0 for cassandra user (and leave all others at default) you ensure it will be the last process (before system level) to be swapped out. But if the system is low on memory then there is no way to prevent the OS from starting to swap for cassandra as well.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-memory